# Unlock objects on specified date/time

Tags: java, delay, timing

I want to implement a function with which I will be able to lock a user account and store a date on which the user account will be unlocked.

Is something like this possible, or only way is do it with `Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a DelayQueue for your purpose.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html

You can put entries into the delayed queue with specifying unlocking time.

Create a blocking delayed queue

```
BlockingQueue queue = new DelayQueue();
```

Then put your object implementing Delayed interface into the queue.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html

```
public class DelayObject implements Delayed {
```

Then you can wait for your objects to expire by using the blocking queue's `take()` method

See this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/java-delay-queue